# Add dupe check parameter to an API call - Contact Form 7 plugin

Tags: api, duplicate-contacts

I've installed the **[Contact Form 7 CiviCRM integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/)** plugin, and it works fine.

I'm just wondering how to add a dupe_check parameter.

If I try something like:

`contact_type=Individual&source=SitoWeb`

it works.

But if I add:

```
contact_type=Individual&source=SitoWeb&dupe_check=1
```

it doesen't.

Here's the section where I have to add those parameters:
[image: screenshot]

Without dupe_check the same contact could be added X times for X times he/she submits the form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the same functionality in the API Explorer?

Basically the Contact Form 7 integration just calls  the CiviCRM API with whatever data is present, so I would expect that if it works in the API Explorer it will work from the Contact Form too.

Comment: To be honest, I don't find any dupe check parameter/functionality in the API Explorer. 

I'm quite new to CiviCRM.

Comment: I do :-) If you do a contact entity and create as action you get a list of parameters. Dupe check is one of them :-)

Comment: Great! This helped a lot!

Actually there is a dupe_check parameter.


In my case, that wasn't working because I didn't have any Unsupervised dedupe rule.

So I've just set the rule I need as Unsupervised...et voila!

This is now working:

`contact_type=Individual&source=SitoWeb&dupe_check=1`


Thank you Erik!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @ErikH - CiviCooP I finally managed to have a duplicate check before creating a new Contact in CiviCRM.

So, first of all, you have to check that you have an Unsupervised dedupe rule for Individuals.

If so, these parameters will work just fine:

```
contact_type=Individual&source=wordpress&dupe_check=1
```

Otherwise, set the rule you want to use as Unsupervised (or create a new one if needed) and use the code above.

Thank you again!